# How to configure Eclipse to complain about the same errors that the Java 8 javadoc tool complains about?

Tags: eclipse, java-8, javadoc

Since Java 8, the javadoc tool that comes with the JDK is quite a bit more picky about malformed HTML, missing parameters, and such. Eclipse's JDT contains a Javadoc parser that can be configured through Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc.

Does anybody know how to configure the Eclipse Javadoc such that it complains exactly about the same errors that the JDK javadoc tool complains about?

These are the settings that I am currently using, but in particular malformed HTML does not seem to be covered here. Or maybe an extra plugin is needed just for checking the HTML in Javadoc blocks in Eclipse?

[image: Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc]

Comment: +1 especially useful if you want to run the javadoc tool as part as a CI build. If you don't, I think you'd better disable these checks when generating the javadoc.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers; Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2);
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Btw: looks like the JDT people do not consider validation of HTML in JavaDoc to be their thing: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368106